# Jenkins/Github: Apparently .git/config doesn't exist?

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration

So after installing the Github plugin to Jenkins CI and attempting to add a job for my Github project to compile automatically after a Github push to master, Jenkins reports that `.git/config` doesn't exist.

I went to `/var/lib/jenkins` and created `.git` and the config file and chowned them to `jenkins:nogroup`.

The error persisted. I then went and did this in my own VPS home directory. Error persists.

I then made a home folder for the jenkins user with no shell and did the same steps. Error persists.

Which `.git/config` is it referring to?!

Edit:

The actual error I'm referring to is:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git config --local credential.helper store --file=\"/tmp/git7406572387997126825.credentials\"" returned status code 255:
stdout: 
stderr: error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved...switched to SSH.

**Steps:**

Assume control of Jenkins user. `su jenkins`
(You may need to set a password for it first (make it good!) `sudo passwd jenkins`.

Go home: `cd ~`.

Generate key: `ssh keygen -t rsa -C "email"`. (No passcode)

Copy $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to Github.

Set Jenkins credentials to authenticate to Github using the private key.

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Found a neat workaround here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/pyv6ldFxUio

1. mkdir ~/.git
2. git config --global user.email "m...@school.com"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/pyv6ldFxUio